# Как в WP создать уникальную страницу со сложной версткой?

Tags: wordpress

Есть верстка для определённой страницы WP, включая ряд картинок и блоков, как реализовать вывод этой страницы по средствам WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов: создайте в админке страницу (не статью. page, а не post). В папке с темой создайте файл вида page-**slug**.php, где **slug** - часть url, следующая после адреса главной страницы вашего wordpress-сайта (при создании страницы называется "ярлык").
В созданном файле располагайте свою сложную вёрстку.

Comment: Ага получилось. А как нагуглить другие варианты и гайды "фром абоу то бьянд"?

Comment: Если вам нужно создать одну такую страницу, то описанный способ будет самым оптимальным. Если это некий шаблон, который нужно применить к коллекции типовых страниц, отличных от стандартного дизайна страницы вашей темы, то гуглите в сторону wordpress page templates. Если описанная страница будет использоваться в качестве главной страницы сайта, то это будет front-page.php

Comment: Способ сработал, все отлично.
Интересует в какую сторону копать если хочу подробней узнать об этом способе и всех подводных камнях его реализации.

Comment: Можно ознакомиться с этой частью документации https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ Ну и дальше уже гуглить непонятные моменты, отталкиваясь от написанного. Подводных камней в общем случае не должно быть. Потому что способ для ваших целей и предусматривался.